# I can't UNLIST a LIST from APPLY function

Tags: r, list, apply

Using the following code in R:

```
maffa_hex = apply(object,2,maffa)
```

produces this: (there are 6000 rows list objects)

```
$`AX-15`
[1] 0.4758193

$`AX-16`
[1] 0.006438442

$`AX-17`
[1] 0.1966381

$`AX-18`
[1] 0.00172522
```

`unlist(maffa_hex)` or `maffa_hex = apply(object,2,unlist(maffa))`
or other alternatives, does not help. I can´t get the numerical values and use them for plotting. The list of list has 6000 rows. The function I am using
is

```
     maffa<-function(x){
      tabx<-table(x)
      if(length(tabx)==1){
        if(names(tabx)=="0"){
          maf <- 0
        }
        if(names(tabx)=="1"){
          maf <- 0.5
        }}
return(NCmisc::Unlist(maf))
    }
```

In the function, I tried return(man), return(unlisted(maf), and also with the NCMisc Package.. no help.

Does anyone knows a solution for this? I hope I don't need to do a Loop!!.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The function you have posted doesn't return anything. Put `return(maf)` at the end of the function.

Comment: The data you have shown, unlists just fine: 
`list('AX-15'= 0.4758193, 'AX-16'= 0.006438442, 'AX-17'= 0.1966381, 'AX-18'= 0.00172522 ) %>% unlist`

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example? Looking at what you have provided, `unlist` should work. Also, in you `maffa` function, what happens if the length of the table is greater than one?

Comment: From the function it doesn´t work

Answer (score 0):

The function did not take care of the NAs, therefore the unlist did not work. There were one entire one column with NAs. This cause the issue of unlist. Thanks all for the prompt reply. I actually realised that with your answers.